# What is wrong with my brakes?

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, trailblazer

2005 chevy trailblazer ext. Hit pothole and now when car stops the pedal goes down a bit and makes a small noise. In hard braking, there is no problem. In soft braking car takes a bit longer to stop. It will stop and then a funny sound comes from brake pedal and it's almost as if the brakes slip a little. This was a problem 7 years ago and it turned out to be the bearings, which were replaced and problem corrected. My question is could it be that the brake fluid has to be flushed from possible air or do you think it is more serious,thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This sounds like it could be an issue with the ABS system, but that's just a gut check. Are there any dash lights?

Comment: I agree on ABS activation at slow speeds. Flushing your fluid probably won't help at all. Which tire hit the pothole and is there any noise while driving? How are your tire pressures?

Answer (score 1):

During hard braking does you're vehicle pull to the left or right at all? Another thing to consider if it is wheel bearings is if you hear a clicking sound when rolling; you might need a mechanic to take a look at it, or if you are mechanically savvy you could put the vehicle on jack stands and check for play in the wheel bearings. Based on the information you've given its difficult to diagnose. Next time you drive it I would pay attention to the following;

-Is there noise coming from the wheels or breaks when you are rolling forward? (not braking)

-Is there pulsing when you press down on the brake pedal?

-Do the brakes grind when you brake?

-Does the vehicle pull to the left or right when braked?

-When the vehicle is parked do you notice any puddles of brake fluid near any of the four wheels or elsewhere under the vehicle?

If you can provide more information we can provide more help!